# How to convert a string into byte[] : on android

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to convert this kind of a string to an array of bytes?

```
String str = "[-11, 33, - 40, ...]";
//byte[] strBytes = ?
```

And I don't want the conversion to change these values.

Comment: Remove the square brackets, split using `,`, loop over resulting array, trim every entry and add it to a byte array. Try that and come back if you have another question.

Answer (score 0):

do this to convert Object to byteArray

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream os = null;
    String myText="hello";
    try {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        os.writeObject(myText);

        byte[] x  = baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the value of x is:
[-84, -19, 0, 5, 116, 0, 15, 91, 45, 49, 49, 44, 32, 51, 51, 44, 32, 45, 32, 52, 48, 93]

now put it in jsonObject

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.putOpt("value", x);
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the value of jsonObject is:

{"value":"[B@a65e6c48"}

again convert it to byte[]

```
    try {
        y = (byte[]) jsonObject.get("value");
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the value of y is:

[-84, -19, 0, 5, 116, 0, 15, 91, 45, 49, 49, 44, 32, 51, 51, 44, 32, 45, 32, 52, 48, 93]

Comment: Yes, then i put it( the array) into a json writer

Comment: of course if you need to put it to json,don't need to convert to byte array ,json accept that it self

Comment: Thank you. I have another issue. how did i use JSONOject to writer on a web page ? i used to use JSONWriter .